# Unable to create an Array of users in Typescript with Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

I'm trying to set an Array of objects (users) as state in my Next app using context.

Here is the code:

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  createContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
} from "react";

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};

type User = {
  _id: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
};

type ContextValue = [User[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<User[]>>];

export const UserContext = createContext<ContextValue>([
  {
    _id: "0",
    firstname: "Tim",
    lastname: "tom",
  },
]);

export function UserComponent({ children }: Props) {
  const [users, setUser] = useState<User[]>([]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[users, setUser]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserComponent;
```

I'm getting an error on the _id property in my array saying:
**Type '{ _id: string; firstname: string; lastname: string; }' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.**

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hey, would it be possible to provide a reproduction sample on codepen or code sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  createContext,
  useState,
} from "react";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type User = {
  _id: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
};

type ContextValue = [User[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<User[]>>];

// keep the default value of context as undefined, since u also have dispatch action u would need to pass both array of users and the dispatch action together
export const UserContext = createContext<ContextValue | undefined>(undefined);

export function UserProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [users, setUser] = useState<User[]>([]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[users, setUser]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

// optionally u could also create a custom hook to access your provider

export const useUserProvider = ()=>{
const context = useContext(UserProvider);
  if(!context) throw new Error('useUserProvider must be used within the 
  scope of UserProvider');
  return context;
}
export default UserProvider;
```

suggest to keep the createContext value as undefined since u would anyways provide the value for the context via the provider which makes the default value here unnecessary, since u have 2 required types in the array, the reason for getting the type error is that your context accepts an array of users as a first argument but on your example u have set it to be an object

```
export const UserContext = createContext<ContextValue>([
  {
    _id: "0",
    firstname: "Tim",
    lastname: "tom",
  },
]);
```

this should be changed to

```
export const UserContext = createContext<ContextValue>([
  [{
    _id: "0",
    firstname: "Tim",
    lastname: "tom",
  }],
  ()=> {} // this will be required based on your type def
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, i placed the array inside of the context value instead of the UseContext state. Totally overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the wrong default value to your context,
replace your initial value of context with this.

```
export const UserContext = createContext<ContextValue>([
    [
        {
            _id: '0',
            firstname: 'Tim',
            lastname: 'tom',
        },
    ],
    () => false,
]);
```

`() => false` is a default function of your dispatch, you can change it for the better.